# OCTAVE - ind2rgb: X must be an indexed image

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to plot and save some meteorological data into png image files using the following lines.

```
imag = data2image(flipud(vari'));
imag = gray2ind(imag);
imwrite(imag,colormap('jet'),'PSFC_RIO_im.png','png');
```

where `data2image` is a custom function that re-scales the data to be usable by image functions.

```
function image = data2image(data)
    HIGH = max(data(:));
    LOW = min(data(:));
    image = (data - LOW)/(HIGH-LOW);
end
```

Unfortunately the `imwrite`complains with the following error:

```
error: ind2rgb: X must be an indexed image
error: called from:
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/ind2rgb.m at line 44, column 5
error:   /usr/local/share/octave/3.6.4/m/image/imwrite.m at line 176, column 16
error:   /home/tufts/Documents/Octave/geomat.m at line 53, column 1
```

Where line 53 is the `imwrite` in the code above. This error makes absolutely no sense to me, as imag was converted to an indexed image with the `gray2ind` function. I also tested this by plotting with `imshow`, which works.

EDIT - class of imag:

```
octave:9> class(imag)
ans = double
```

Comment: Seems to be okay in Matlab R2012b. You might try changing your variable names from `imag` and `image` to something else. Both are names of common builtin functions.

Comment: what is the class/data type of `imag`?

Comment: @Shai, how do I check for data type?

Comment: @horchler, I changed the variable name, without prevail.

Comment: @Shai, check edit. I have annexed the data type of the variable.

Comment: try casting `imag` to `uint8` make sure range is proper

Comment: @Shai, perfect! And it makes total sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question after accidentally, in an unrelated problem, figuring out how.

Indexed images in MATLAB have a minimum value of 1. My function was getting the minimum value of the data, and making that equal to 0.

Take care of that, and you solve the problem